# Interactive 3D histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, histogram, interactive

How to make an interactive 3D histogram that can rotate?

This is my R code for the 3D histogram. (z is a matrix)

```
hist3D(z=z, border="black",  axes=TRUE, space=0.2, label=TRUE,ylab="Control", xlab="Treatment", zlab="Frequency",theta = 40, phi = 25,bty = "g",nticks=2,  col=c("yellow","green", "red"), colvar=colvar, main="3D Histogram: Treatment Vs. Control", colkey = FALSE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that the community can more easily and quickly help you. Things like packages used, an example of your data, and a description of the problem you face (e.g. does your current code produce an error? If so, what is the error message).

Comment: I am using library(plot3D) and the function hist3D. With hist3D I reproduce a 3d histogram that is static. I would like to create an interactive histogram that can rotate itself so that we can see all its perspectives